# Git partial merge conflict resolve in a file with vimdiff

Tags: git, vim, git-merge-conflict, vimdiff

During a merge conflict resolution, is there a way to resolve only some conflicts of a file without marking this file as "solved" or checkout the file as conflicted without loosing the hunks already edited?

Currently I'm using vimdiff as mergetool. I have some files that I did a "partial" conflict resolution, but when exit vimdiff with `:wqa` the file is automatically marked as "solved".

**PS:** I know I could use `git checkout --conflict=merge myfile.txt` to reset all the conflicts hunks in the file, but I wouldn't keep the conflicts I've already solved as I need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying it I see the mergetool helper's not set up to handle changing the file and not adding it; if you write changed content but take an error exit from vimdiff (with `:cq`) it resets the file.

But nothing's stopping you from doing this yourself. Mergetool's just a convenience wrapper around

```
vimdiff -c '4winc w' -c 'winc J' `git checkout-index --stage=all myfile.txt`
```

that does some additional renaming and reordering to make it a little easier to id which is which, cleans up after itself, and either `git add`s the result (if you don't `:cq`) or `git checkout -m`'s it if you do. So do that vimdiff yourself and remember b1 b2 b3 is git's stage 1 2 3 content i.e. base ours theirs you can fix up the main file however you want without the helper helpfully `git add`ing the result, you'll want to `rm .merge_file_*`  at some point to clean up the temps.

Or to do this after-the-fact, if you want to keep the partially-merged `myfile.txt` that `git mergetool` so confidently added as a completed resolution, (edit: it kept bugging me how clunky the way I knew was, sure enough there's been a direct way to do it since oh, Git v1.4 or so)

```
git update-index --unresolve myfile.txt
```